# Programatically Add/Remove nodes from Service Fabric cluster

Tags: c#, .net, azure-service-fabric

I know I can use PowerShell commands as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-windows-server-add-remove-nodes)

```
.\AddNode.ps1 -NodeName VM5 -NodeType NodeType0 -NodeIPAddressorFQDN 182.17.34.52 -ExistingClientConnectionEndpoint 182.17.34.50:19000 -UpgradeDomain UD1 -FaultDomain fd:/dc1/r0 -AcceptEULA
```

```
.\RemoveNode.ps1 -ExistingClientConnectionEndpoint 182.17.34.50:19000
```

However, I'd like to do the same from a .NET application. I looked at [`FabricClient.ClusterManagementClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient.clustermanagementclient) documentation and there are methods to activate/deactivate nodes, but nothing about adding/removing them.

Comment: The PowerShell commands you referenced are for a stand alone cluster running on-premises (not in Azure).  Is that your scenario or are you running the cluster in Azure?  For the latter, you're going to have to get to the underlying virtual machine scale set to change the capacity (add/remove node).

Comment: I'm running an on-prem cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are public managed APIs for said functionality available through Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.dll DeploymentManager class, which the powershell scripts are wrapping. You can find this in the Standalone package DeploymentComponents folder.

If you choose to consume the APIs in this way, note you will need to have DeploymentComponents resources local to the imported assembly.

We are looking into improving the dev experience for this in the future, possibly through the use of a nuget package.